# How do you pass a variable as a column name in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have recently created a script which allows a user to both filter a table and then sort the remaining columns into ascending and descending order. This is what i wrote:

```
    if 'desc' in request.form:
        if request.form['desc'] == 'date_time':
            display_test_results = test_result.query.order_by(desc(test_result.date_time)).filter(or_(test_result.date_time.like('%' +global_value_detailed+ '%'),                                                          
                                                    test_result.place_of_test.like('%' +global_value_detailed+ '%'),
                                                    test_result.part_number.like('%' +global_value_detailed+ '%'),
                                                    test_result.serial_number.like('%' +global_value_detailed+ '%'),
                                                    test_result.test_details.like('%' +global_value_detailed+ '%'),
                                                    test_result.result.like('%' +global_value_detailed+ '%')))

            return render_template('/detailed_test_data.html', title='Database Full', display_test_results=display_test_results)

        elif request.form['desc'] == 'part_number':
```

Then repeated this for all of my columns, the issue here is that i have 17 columns ( not all have been used in this example.) So to get ascending and descending sorting working I have 34 batches of code accounting to 900 lines. This is a huge amount of code which will slow down the productivity of my search/sorting feature ( i presume.)

Is there way of using a refined code, where the request.form['desc'] value is saved as a variable, then that variable used to tell the query which column to look at? I assume it would eventually look something similar to the code bellow. But when i run this code i get the error trackback bellow it.

```
 if request.form['desc'] != '':
                    order_column = request.form['desc']

                    display_test_results = test_result.query.order_by(desc(test_result.order_column)).filter(or_(test_result.date_time.like('%' +global_value_primary+ '%'),
                                                                                                            test_result.place_of_test.like('%' +global_value_primary+ '%'),
                                                                                                            test_result.serial_number.like('%' +global_value_primary+ '%'),
                                                                                                            test_result.result.like('%' +global_value_primary+ '%'))).filter(test_result.test_details=='Overall').all()
                    return render_template('/primary_test_data.html', title='', display_test_results=display_test_results)

 elif request.form['asc'] != '':
                    order_column = request.form['asc'] ...
```

AttributeError: type object 'test_result' has no attribute 'order_column'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**getattr**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

`.order_by(desc(getattr(test_result, request.form['desc'])))`